# Pokemon go: login with 4g impossible

Tags: pokemon-go

I cant login on pokemon go with my 4g, but when I login with wifi I can walk away with 4g and the app works perfectly fine.

Although you do not always have internet accesable, I need to be able to login with 4g :-)

I have a huawei y6 pro
Android system: 5.1
I have tried restarting the app, my phone, reinstalling ....basically the basic stuff

Comment: If your [previous question is closed as off-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/315300/162442), asking it again is not the correct course of action.

Comment: Guys coman, I have already read all other articles about this, but they do not help... well well if you say so, a fallen brother will go away

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the marked question as this is asking for a specific problem with 4G vs. Wifi which is not related to the GO servers.  I think the question might have already been asked somewhere else, but the linked question is entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well

**Why is it happening?**

At the first launch of the app, a setting must have been selected automatically that restricts data access to the Pokemon go app.

**How to fix**

Go to:

1. Settings of the phone
2. Go to the apps section of your settings
3. Click on "reset app preferences" in that section, and then launch the app.

**Downfalls**

This will reset the app preferences for every app, which means that when you launch an app, it will again ask you a prompt for access to a certain feature on your phone. For example, Gallery will ask for permission to your photos the next time you open it.

Comment: Bit it seems it dosent work, and the example, the gallery, does not ask for permission either. I deleted all data relater to pokemon go, bit i still cant login, bit i will try your method when i get wifi

Comment: @Danielaakhus did you click on reset app preferences?

Comment: Yes, but notting happened...

Comment: @Danielaakhus That's weird. That button should reset app preferences for EVERY app, including gallery. Try googling how to reset app preferences on your specific device

Comment: This discussion is a rather apt example as to why we don't allow re-asking the same question.

Comment: @Frank Oh! I didn't notice that he asked it twice